# Fragment Replace null pointer exception

Tags: android-fragments

I am trying to replace fragment with another inside a onItemClick of list view and i want to send a selected item name from list fragment to another fragment but its showing null pointer exception

@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view, int position,
            long id)
    {

```
try
    {
        Log.e("----- inside onItemClick -----", citySelected);

        MapVisibleFragment newFragment = new MapVisibleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("CITYNAME", citySelected);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        ((BaseContainerFragment) getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(
                newFragment, true);

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

but the same concept is working inside button click for the below one

```
 try 
 {
     ListFragmentFromDBRecords2 newFragment = new ListFragmentFromDBRecords2();
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putStringArrayList("names", allData);
     newFragment.setArguments(args);
     ((BaseContainerFragment) getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(
      newFragment, true);

     Log.d("--->>>>", allData.toString());

    } 
 catch (Exception e) 
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: here showing null pointer excetion ((BaseContainerFragment) getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(
                newFragment, true);

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

```
((BaseContainerFragment) getParentFragment())
```

is null for you. Check why `getParentFragment()` method returns null.

Comment: Actually my code does't have the comment. please may i know the correct one

Comment: I refer to your comment on your question :)